# Is bootstrap too heavy for smartphone?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm feeling like it's getting heavier since I started using bootstrap.
With PC, I don't feel it's laggy but with my iPhone.

Do we usually have to cut down CSS frame work to the limit as little as possible?
But it'll be too much work to find out what is used in my CSS and what is not.

Anyone has any good idea about this?

Comment: well usually boots are a lot bigger than smartphones, so yes.  definitely too heavy.

Comment: Is it your images/other assets or Bootstrap?

Answer (score 3):

It's not too heavy. You can, however, customize it and get only the parts you need. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: Even stripping it down for basic CRUD processing, good luck getting minified CSS under 100KB -- by no metric is TB lightweight. Big fan in general, but for mobile phones there is an impact, which is why questions like these arise.